# What is the polynomial to use in the Massey-Omura cryptosystem?

Tags: finite-field

The Massey-Omura cryptosystem uses "multiplication over the finite field $GF(2^n)$. I'm just starting understand the idea of multiplying polynomials and I've searched for online calculators to use for this. Thing is, all of these calculators request that I enter some sort of polynomial modulus and I don't know which one the cryptosystem uses.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it doesn't matter (as long as the polynomial is prime, of course).

For any $n$, there's only one finite field $GF(2^n)$, however there are a number of ways of mapping those elements to bit patterns.  We call that mapping a *representation*; one method of generating such a representation is to use a prime polynomial of degree $n+1$.

Now, between any two representations of $GF(2^n)$, there will be a mapping that converts values in one representation into values in the other; if both representations are sane (by which I mean that they perform addition by bit-wise exclusive-or of the representation), then this mapping will be linear (and hence, cheap to compute).

In Massey-Omura, the sides exchange the representations of the field elements $m^a$, $m^{ab}$, $m^b$; if there was a representation that makes this exchange weak, then the attacker could convert these three elements into that weak representation, find the value $m$ in that weak representation, and then map it back into the original representation, breaking MO in the supposedly strong representation.  Hence, no representation is any stronger or weaker than any other -- the choice of representation is strictly a practical matter.

In fact, if you go to the patent, Massey and Omura suggest using a normal representation (which is an alternative to a polynomial representation); in normal representations, the operation of squaring is cheap, and they believe that this will make computing exponentiation cheaper overall.  Again, this is a practical consideration -- it has no impact on security.

I will leave off with one security issue: [people have recently made significant progress](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/400.pdf) in computing discrete logs over $GF(p^m)$ for small $p$ (and 2 is as small as we can get), and smooth $m$.  Because of this, it would appear to be wise to select a prime value of $n$; that way, these recent results do not apply.

Comment: How do I know if a polynomial is "prime" (that makes no sense) and how do I determine the correct (or a correct) polynomial to use on the fly for any given n? What is a normal representation? What would a field representation for GF(2^8) look like?

Comment: @Melab: A polynomial is prime if it isn't the product of two smaller polynomials; for example, $x^2+x+1$ is prime, while $x^2+1 = (x+1)\times(x+1)$ is not.  As for determining a valid representation on the fly for an arbitrary $n$, well, I don't know of a cheap way.  Until you learn more, I'd suggest you stick with a fixed value of $n$ (and use a known valid polynomial).

Comment: How is $x+1$ a factor polynomial of $x^2+1$?

Comment: @Melab: What is $(x+1) \times (x+1)$ (doing arithmetic in $GF(2)$)?

Comment: Ooooh. I get what you are saying.

Comment: @Melab, as a complement of Poncho, we use the term "irreducible"  polynomial, because in K[X] irreducible is equivalent to Prime. You can understand that $(X+1).(X+1)=X^2+1$ is reducible in $GF(2)$, and $P(X)=X^2+X+1$ is irreducible in $GF(2)$. This P can be used to generate an extension field denoted by $GF(2^2)$ and the extension is of degré 2, the same degre of P. $GF(2^2)$ is called the spliting field of $GF(2)$ and its element are represented as $(a,b)=a.\alpha + b$ with $a, b \in GF(2)$. And $\alpha$ a root of P ! is looks like the extension de $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Melab,and to understand what a "Normal Bassis is" ? In fact any field (finite or not) can be viewed as a Vectorial Space, and then admits a basis. You already know the polynomial basis ${1, X, \cdots, X^n, \cdots}$. But there is  more basis. if you get $\alpha$ the root of the irreduccible polynomial which generate the field, a normal basis id ${1, \alpha, \cdots, (\alpha)^{2^n}, \cdots}$. And in a finite extension there is some interesting property as those pointed out by Poncho.